# Is it bad to use Auto Gold ATF DM in a transmission that only requires Dexron VI

Tags: chevrolet, automatic-transmission, impala, dexron-vi

I have put Auto Gold ATF DM in my transmission in a 2008 chevy impala that only requires DEXRON VI. On the back of the Auto Gold ATF DM transmission fluid, it says "not for use in automatic transmissions requiring GM Dexron VI etc. Is this a bad thing. will it cause my transmission to go out or damage it. Will it be okay to drive everyday.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: This answer has some interesting info if you have not need it. GM bulletin clearly states that V3 should not be used in V4 transmissions, because the transmissions were not *designed* to use it. https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/22657/will-mixing-dexron-vi-with-another-transmission-fluid-damage-the-transmission

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your question? You are stating you used an ATF which specifically states *not to use* in a transmission which normally uses DEXRON VI and you're asking if that's a bad thing? If that's the gist of your question, then, YES IT'S A VERY BAD THING. If you haven't ran the transmission, get it drained without running it and put DEXRON back into it. If you've ran it, you'll at a minimum need to have the transmission flushed, then have DEXRON VI added back in. Then there's no promise you haven't done damage to the transmission already. Only time will tell, but chances are pretty good you have done damage.